# php stdClass/object build

Tags: php, angularjs, loops

i want to build an object (for angular) so it will look like so

```
user:{
        {education:
                {high school:'some school'},
                {faculty:'faculty of science'}
       },
       {skills:
                {skill1:'sk1'},
                {skill2:'sk2'}
       }
}
```

and this is my php and mysql query:

```
$testArr = array();
    $user = new stdClass();
    $params =  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT param.*, sys_param_values.*,param_value.*,type_user.*,
                                       param.name AS paramName, 
                                       doc_param.name AS docParamName 
                                       FROM param
                                       LEFT JOIN doc_param ON param.doc_param_id = doc_param.id
                                       LEFT JOIN sys_param_values ON param.id = sys_param_values.param_id
                                       LEFT JOIN param_value ON sys_param_values.value_ref = param_value.id
                                       LEFT JOIN type_user ON sys_param_values.ref_user_id = type_user.id"));
```

query result:

```
"params":[{"id":21,"name":"faculty","type_id":5,"doc_param_id":14,"created_at":"2015-05-17 14:13:12","updated_at":"2015-06-04 08:19:43","doc_type":12,"ref_user_id":21,"param_id":48,"iteration":null,"value_short":null,"value_long":null,"value_ref":74,"value":"some High","type":"tech-admin","email":"xxxxxxx8@gmail.com","password":"$2y$10$6L8voJ3DgZuADHZLaBh4jei\/U.svVdcN4B02XFc9mF\/p8m5RpfJtG","password_new":null,"first_name":"jon","last_name":"snow","street_1":"shiv","street_2":"tey","city":"123456","state":"aa","zipcode":"47252","country":"usa","phone_1":"123456","phone_2":"123456","mobile":"123456789","date_of_birth":"2015-05-18 11:25:42","registration":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","last_login":"2015-05-20 09:14:52","send_newsletters":1,"send_notifications":1,"remember_token":"dtlimLNZBWdCxcqKR7NdDblMiafkZOxywN4jjUac53v7NI4e1t6eokJXdsoy","paramName":"faculty","docParamName":"education"}
```

after the query witch is good, i loop :

```
    foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
        $paramName = $v->paramName;
        $value = $v->value;
        $testArr[$v->docParamName] =  array();
        $testArr[$v->docParamName][$paramName] = $v->value;
    }
```

and the result is :

```
"test":{
        "education":
                  {"high_school":"some High"},
        "skills":
                  {"skill_1":"skill_1 Value"},
        "experience":
                  {"xp_1":"xp1 value"}
         }
```

the thing is i have more if these parameters for example "skill_2" and "skill_3" that are suppose to go in the "skills" object. 
but this loop anly gets the last parameter..

where am i suppose to specify a key or something so that all of the skills go to the skills object and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to define like this:-

```
foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
        $paramName = $v->paramName;
        $value = $v->value;
       // $testArr[$v->docParamName] =  array(); // comment the line
        $testArr[$v->docParamName][$paramName] = $v->value;
    }
```

Note:- the line is commented because you already defined `$testArr` as an array before `foreach` loop.thanks

Comment: it is already defined as an array. just above the query wich is just above the loop, everything you see is in the same function

Comment: great to hear that your problem is solved and thanks for marking and up voting. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are **re-initializing** your sub-object on each iteration:

```
$testArr[$v->docParamName] = array(); // <- By this, you remove all previously 
                                      //    assigned values
$testArr[$v->docParamName][$paramName] = $v->value;
```

Initializing an array before appending elements to it is a good idea, because it will otherwise trigger a warning when you try to append to a non-initialized array. But you **should only initialize the array if it was not initialized before**:

```
if (!array_key_exists($v->docParamName, $testArr)) {
    $testArr[$v->docParamName] =  array();
}
$testArr[$v->docParamName][$paramName] = $v->value;
```